# Flot auto adjust minimum value

Tags: scale, flot, autoscaling, minmax

I want set a minimum value for a Flot graph, but if a value is available beyond the minimum value it should auto-scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this.

You'll need to loop through your points before plotting, and if any of them exceed your minimum value, then don't provide the axis min.